# Is there a system that takes tactics over skill, and skill over dumb luck?

Tags: game-recommendation, homebrew, tactics

This is my first post. StackExchange is an incredible community, thank to you!

I'm writing an RPG system and I'm looking for systems to inspire me with the following characteristics:

1. The PCs are humans and have human limitations. The strongest man won't be able to lift a ton, the fastest won't outrun a horse, nor can one take a sword through the chest and walk away like nothing happened. Actually, you have to have tactics, skill and luck just to not die like a fly in combat. That means I want it gritty. Combat is not your first option.
2. You can face powerful enemies with tactics, "dirty" tricks, numeric advantage, surprise, etc. like you would in real life. You face a dragon with intelligence, deception and traps, not using your infinity plus one sword.
3. The player's ingenuity is encouraged, because most of times he will be against hard odds. In my system, the attribute + skill formula add to a maximum of 8, the mean is 4. The only die is a d6 giving a modifier of -1, 0 or +1. The circumstantial modifiers can range from -4 to +4. So, although luck plays a role, it's minimal: skills, attributes and tactics means the most. Even then, no matter the capacity of the PCs, if the players can come up with a reasonable plan I will let them try their hands at it. Tactics over skill, and skill over dumb luck.
4. Classless, point-buy skill based. A small skill list (not much over 30), with broad skills, with escalating costs over upgrades. One skill point means a lot.
5. Preferably a generic system. Not an overly big ruleset. About 20 pages of basic rules is enough, so that it takes 20 minutes or less to create a PC.
6. Preferably use common d6 dice exclusively.
7. Magic is optional. There can be low magic, but it has to be rare enough that many don't believe it. Still, being able to read people's minds, cast an illusion and talk to the dead is incredible as it wold be in real life, and can be central to the plot of an entire scenario.

As English is not my first language, I hope I was clear enough and the points I made give you an idea of what I want. Thank you all!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Unfortunately a couple months ago we decided not to allow game recommendation questions any more, so this question (which would otherwise be quite good!) is almost certain to be closed.

Comment: Now that you've got the rep you should definitely stop by [chat]. A couple of people have dropped ideas there already!

Comment: @Oblivious Sage Thank you! How can I rewrite my post if game recommendations and asking for ideas on homebrew are off topic. I mean, by what I read on tags info I'm better asking in a rpg forum, but if there is another way... Well, I will try the chat, and ask more specific and on topic questions on another post.

Comment: @OriomLyraLisboa You are correct, for something like this there is just no way to “fix” the question—because there’s *nothing wrong* with the question, there’s something wrong with *this site* (which is that it’s bad at discussion and idea-generation, which is by design because it makes us better at Q&A, but we still have to acknowledge that there is a tradeoff there that makes us bad at answering these kinds of questions).